# How do I say this sentence informally?

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice

> この習慣は日本に特有のものです。

But if I were to ask a question, この習慣は日本に特有のものか would have a negative tone so what word do I use instead?

Comment: This is pretty confusing and the question title doesn’t seem to match the body. Do you need the original sentence or the question form of it? What is “negative tone” and for which word do you need replacement?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky yes sorry I wrote it a bit confusing, I want to know how to say the original sentence as an informal question.

Comment: What about simply saying: `この習慣は日本に特有?` Or `この習慣は日本に特有なの?`

Comment: why do you think it sounds negative?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-ものか-mono-ka/

Comment: I know there's an excellent explanation about this on the site, but it sounds like this is a general question about forming questions in informal speech rather than about ものか. Generally speaking, か is not used in informal questions.

Comment: @user27223 I'd expect that ～ものか used this way.. 「この習慣は日本に特有だ/です。」→「この習慣**が**日本に特有**なものか** ！」 or.. 「～特有のものだ/です。」→「特有のもの**なもんか** ！」

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> この習慣は日本に特有のものです。

To turn it to an informal question, you could use...

> この習慣は日本に特有のもの？
>   この習慣は日本に特有のものなの？

(Here, the もの is a normal noun, 物.)

---

The [ものか that you're talking about](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B-mono-ka/) is a sentence ending particle (終助詞). I'd expect it used this way..

「この習慣は日本に特有だ。」
→ 「この習慣が日本に特有**なものか**！/特有**なもんか**！」